# Unable to find file location inside jar file being executed from task scheduler

Tags: java, windows, jar, scheduled-tasks

I have a jar file which I execute from the task scheduler in windows, however it gives following error:

```
java.io.FileNotFoundException: C:\windows\system32\internal\config.properties (The system cannot find the path specified)
    at java.io.FileInputStream.open0(Native Method)
    at java.io.FileInputStream.open(Unknown Source)
    at java.io.FileInputStream.<init>(Unknown Source)
    at java.io.FileInputStream.<init>(Unknown Source)
    at com.FetchApis.<clinit>(FetchApis.java:35)
    at com.App.main(App.java:110)
Exception in thread "main" java.lang.NullPointerException
        at com.App.main(App.java:120)
Press any key to continue . . .
```

The internal folder is present in `C:\Users\usr\Desktop\dTest\internal`

If i execute the jar file directly it does not give this error, but when task scheduler initiates it, the error is thrown. How can this be resolved?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'm not sure how the windows task scheduler works, but it looks like you need to set the working directory of your task to `C:\Users\usr\Desktop\dTest\`.

If this is not possible with the windows task scheduler, then you can set it for java by passing the `-Duser.dir=C:\Users\usr\Desktop\dTest\` argument to the JVM.